# wwwizer not working on Chrome

Tags: django, google-chrome, openshift

My domain name is registered on 123 reg.  The web app is built in django and hosted using redhat's openshift.  In order to use my own domain name (rather than the default openshift url) I've created an alias using a CNAME record in 123 reg.  To allow a naked domain redirect I'm using http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect.

This works when I'm on firefox but not on Chrome (depriving me of a lot of android mobile traffic).

Am I doing something wrong with wwwizer? And if not are there any alternatives to wwwizer out there or can I set up 123 reg DNS settings differently to allow the naked domain?

The A record I set up for wwwizer to redirect (on my DNS settings in 123 reg) looks like this:

@       A           174.129.24.170

And the CNAME record to redirect to my alias looks like this:

www     CNAME           myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com

I also have MX records in the DNS settings set up for Gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong ip.

Correct one:

> 174.129.25.170

Everything else is fine.

Comment: Oh I didn't.... wait... I did.  I feel bad getting any reputation points for this but.....